# How is the RHS related to the LHS

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Please explain the following relationship:[image]

Accessible:

```
2 --> 18
20 --> 48
200 --> 6
2000 --> 26
How did I arrive at these?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you wrote the

> numbers as Roman numerals, converted to numbers using A1 - Z26, and summed

like this

> 2 → II → 9 + 9 = 18
>  20 → XX → 24 + 24 = 48
>  200 → CC → 3 + 3 = 6
>  2000 → MM → 13 + 13 = 26